# What does "turn" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I understand the quotation from poem "If" by Rudyard Kipling, but I don't understand the meaning of the word "turn" in its context

> If you can force your heart and nerve and sinew to serve your turn long after they are gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Serve one's/its turn](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/serve-one's/its-turn)*** is an idiomatic expression that means:

> - Be useful or helpful:
>
>   - *now that they have served their turn, cut some of them out
>       suppressing his ire would hardly serve his turn at this juncture*

(ODO)

- it's a  passage about how a person's willpower can win over the weaknesses of the flesh.